# Проект на React App. Не могу достать value из react-компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Делаю поиск. Для поиска необходимо данные, введенные в окно SearchBar, перенести в  url.

```
  render() {
  return (
      <section className="search-field">
          <h2>Поля</h2>
          <div id="search-bar" className="row">
              <div className="col-md-5">
                  <SearchBar className="form-control" id="searchBar" name="searchBar" ref="search"/>
              </div>
          </div>
      <div>
      </div>

      <div className='row b-list-caret'>
          {this.renderUsersList()}
      </div>
  </section>
 );
}
```

Присваиваю value вот так:

```
let queryString = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control').value;
let url = 'http://46.236.137.153/search/field?query=';

console.log( queryString );
```

Вывожу в консоль для начала чисто ту часть, которую нужно присоединить к url. Консоль выводит "undefined". Что не так?

Код SearchBar:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" className="input-group">
            <input type="text"
                   className = "form-control"
                   id = "search-string"
                   ref = "search"
                   defaultValue = "hello"
            />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
                <button className="btn btn-default" type="button">OK</button>
            </span>
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: let queryString = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control').value - это не правильно. Вы выбираете коллекцию. Какое у нее может быть value? Нужен 1 элемент или обход коллекции в цикле

Comment: `document.querySelector('.form-control')`, если элемент у вас один такой на странице. Хотя странно что вы пытаетесь делать что-то из вне, а не делаете внутри реакта с его экосистемой

Answer (score 1):

Используйте экосистему React:

```js
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      queryString: "hello"
    };

    this.handleChanges = this.handleChanges.bind(this);
    this.confirmedQuery = this.confirmedQuery.bind(this);
  }

  handleChanges(event) {
    this.setState({
      queryString: event.target.value
    });
  }
  
  confirmedQuery() {
    const baseUrl = "http://46.236.137.153/search/field";
    const url = `${baseUrl}?query=${this.state.queryString}`;

    const { onChanged } = this.props;
    onChanged && onChanged(url);
  }

  render() {
    const { queryString } = this.state;
    return (
      <form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" className="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="search-string"
          ref="search"
          value={queryString}
          onChange={this.handleChanges}
        />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button className="btn btn-default" type="button" onClick={this.confirmedQuery}>
            OK
          </button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onChanged = this.onChanged.bind(this);
    this.renderUsersList = this.renderUsersList.bind(this);
  }

  onChanged(url) {
    console.log(url);
  }

  renderUsersList() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="search-field">
        <h2>Поля</h2>
        <div id="search-bar" className="row">
          <div className="col-md-5">
            <SearchBar
              className="form-control"
              id="searchBar"
              name="searchBar"
              ref="search"
              onChanged={this.onChanged}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row b-list-caret">{this.renderUsersList()}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('form-control').value
```

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает `HTMLCollection`, а collection как вы понимаете это не один элемент это скорее массив из элементов ну или пустой мвссив. У массива нет пропсы `value` и значит она `undefined`.

А вообще соглашусь с предыдущим ответом, вам очень не помешало ознакомится с документацией по react и его экосистеме. Что-бы писать хороший код! То что вы сейчас мешаете бульон из react и классического js - это очень плохо!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onChange={handlerLogin} className={styles.formField} placeholder="Логин" type="Email" />
```

---

```
 const handlerLogin = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.value);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]